# Proof about the convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

In another question here, we were given an identity based off a sequence:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_{n+1}-\frac{a_n}{2} = 0$

I tried to show that the sequence converges. However, I am very uncertain whether my proof is correct or not.

If we assume $a_n$ diverges:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} -\frac{1}{2}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-\frac{a_n}{2}}{a_n} \rightarrow \frac{0}{\infty} = 0$

This contradicts the assumption that the sequence diverges due to the ratio test, and it must thus be false.

Comment: It's hard to understand: **what is the sequence, anyway**?

Comment: "This contradicts our assumption due to the ratio test": what assumption does it contradict? This is exactly the assumption we have. Anyway, what sequence are you talking about, and what do you apply the ratio test to?

Comment: @DonAntonio The sequence is not given.

Comment: @Crostul The assumption is that the sequence diverges... I'll edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: It is **not true** that the limit is $0$ if the sequence diverges. Consider for example $a_n=10^n$. Then you're talking about the limit of $9\frac12, 95, 950, 9500, \ldots$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm.. But does your sequence fullfil the requirement of the first equation?

Comment: @HenningMakholm That is the hypothesis. He has to prove that $a_n$ converges under that assumption.

Comment: @Avatrin: No, that's why it is a counterexample: It _does not satisfy_ what you want to prove, but it _does_ satisfy the secret assumption you stated in a comment above: that the $a_n$s diverge.

Comment: @HenningMakholm $$\lim_{n \to \infty} 10^{n+1}- 10^n/2 = + \infty \neq 0$$ the hypothesis is not satisfied.

Comment: @Crostul: Correct. That is the point! The hypothesis that $a_n$ diverges (which the OP disclosed in comment 4 above) _is_ satisfied, though. Therefore the OP needs _more_ assumptions than that hypothesis to show that the limit is $0$.

Comment: That is the hypothesis. Why are you talking about a sequence not satisfying the hypothesis?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think you misunderstand the proof. The sequence must fulfill the requirement of the first equation. To prove that any sequence that fulfills the requirement of the equation remust converge, I show that it cannot diverge. I do that through contradiction.

Comment: @Avatrin: You can't just start by asserting that your sequence satisfies _the thing you have to prove_ about it.

Comment: @Avatrin You are aware that "$a_n$ diverges" is not the same as "$a_n\to+\infty$"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Finally critique that makes sense. Yes, that does ruin my argument. Thank you!

Comment: Did you think of showing that $\lim a_n=0$? this is not hard to show.

Comment: What a waste of comments by knowledgeable people...and all because a rather poorly worded question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite clear what you are trying to prove. Is it that $a_n$ is a convergent *series*, i.e. $\sum_n a_n$ is finite, or that it is a convergent *sequence*, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists and is finite?

For the first, this is not true and the fallacy is that you've assumed that if it isn't a convergent series then $a_n\to\infty$. For example, setting $a_n=\frac1n$ satisfies the original condition, but doesn't give a convergent series.

For the second, this is true, but the ratio test is not relevant (it is a test for convergence of the series, not the sequence). Your proof also doesn't work because it only shows that $a_n\not\to\infty$, but the sequence could conceivably fail to converge because there is no limit, rather than because the limit is infinite.

In fact we must have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. To see this, note that for any $\delta>0$ we have some $N$ such that $|a_{n+1}|\leq|a_n|/2+\delta$ for all $n\geq N$. Thus $|a_{N+2}|\leq |a_{N+1}|/2+\delta\leq|a_N|/4+\delta+\delta/2$. Continuing in this manner, you can show that $|a_{N+k}|< 2^{-k}|a_N|+2\delta$ for every $k$, and so for all $k$ sufficiently large you get $|a_{N+k}|<3\delta$.

(In fact a sequence satisfies your original condition if and only if it tends to $0$; if $\lim a_n=0$ then $\lim(a_{n+1}-a_n/2)=0-0/2=0$.)

Comment: [reply to a deleted comment] Yes, it's true that passing the ratio test implies that the sequence tends to $0$ (because that must be true whenever the series converges). But it's no help for testing if a sequence is convergent to something other than $0$, which is why I thought you might be trying to show the series was convergent (if I'd known the question asked you to show specifically that it converged to $0$, I wouldn't have thought that).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I actually deleted my comment before you posted since I realized the test was useless for my purpose. So, yeah, with this clarification, my question has been answered completely.